# Detection of completion of a tree browsing with RxJS

Tags: angular, recursion, rxjs

I'm encountering a design problem with RxJS. I've spent a significant time with the documentation but I didn't find any clue.
So, if anyone can help me...

I am browsing a tree loaded from a remote host.
The code below summarizes very simply the flow.

```
public load(id: string) {
    this.httpClient.get<Result>('https://...', { headers })
      .subscribe(result => {
        result.parents.forEach(parent => {
          this.load(parent.id);
        });
      });
  }
```

My problem is simple. I want to detect the browsing completion.
Is there any combination of XXXMap to fulfill this goal ?

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with rxjs design. This is more of your problem requirement.

Comment: What u mean with "browsing completion"? If you mean you want to wait till all ? `parents` are loaded you need to create inner observables for all the entries in your `parents`array. When all inner observables emitted there values, then you know you are down.

Comment: The parents have parents. To complete the parents array as you've suggested, I need to re-invoke the load function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
public loadTree(id: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.load(id)
        .pipe(
            map(res => res.parents)
            mergeMap(
                parents => of(...parents).pipe(
                    mergeMap(
                        (parent) => {
                            return this.loadTree(parent.id);
                        }
                    )
                )
            ),
            toArray(),
        );
}

public load(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Result>(`https://.../${id}`, { headers });
}
```

`loadTree` calls your http-method. After you received your response `map` will get the `parents` Array. After this, it takes your array and splits it with the spread array into single `parent`Objects. For each of those `parent`objects it will call the `load` method again. `toArray` collects all of the inner observables to match the starting return type. You need to check if the code fits into your project (call type/return type).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. But it looks like to me that the ```return this.load(parent.id)``` terminate the browse before the end. We just get the parents, and we never reach the grand-parents

Comment: You are right, should be recursive, edited it. Try this and start `this.loadTree(firstId).subscribe()` in your ngOnInit or inside the constructor. A minimal reproducable example would help a lot.

Comment: I will provide a sample dataset for testing purpose. Meanwhile, I can already discard your last proposal. `loadTree` is a void function. Therefore, ```return this.loadTree(parent.id)``` is inoperative.

Comment: Didnt edited the return type, but the return in the beginning of the method should be recognized by you.

Comment: Should work as intended. Cant try it right now. You can also check several blog entries which explain how to call recursive https://dev.to/krumpet/getting-a-recursive-data-structure-asynchronously-with-rxjs-46b9 . You could also use `flatMap` and `forkJoin` instead of my `spread` and `concatMap`

Comment: And the limitation with the number of chars complicate my life to provide sample data. Anyway... It's working :-).  I detect the completion. I am not quite sure to be determinist on the resulting data emitted by loadTree. But I can handle my requirement in the pipe process.